# Machine ADB conflicting with Expo ADB

Tags: android, react-native, express, expo, adb

So, basically i'm developing this app with react native and expo, this app uses axios to call my backend service running on localhost:3000, which i use adb reverse to use on my phone.
The problem is: while developing on my machine with Zorin OS, the adb reverse + expo works greatly, but whenever i try to do the same in Windows, i get the message:

```
> adb reverse tcp:3000 tcp:3000
adb server version (36) doesn't match this client (41); killing...
* daemon started successfully
3000
```

which to my understanding just kills the adb process expo is using, which disconnects my phone from the expo client. any solution to this?

Comment: The common way is to specify the adb executable in an environment variable like `ADB`. Other tools use this variable and then ignore their own adb version. Not sure about Expo.